# Error handling for special types of $resource request errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have a working Angular app that makes requests to a REST API through a `$resource` service I have set up.  Everything works well - I have callbacks for my success and error conditions, and if it is an "expected" error I have a service that knows how to parse the `httpResponse` to show a message that will be meaningful to the user - HTTP codes, special application error codes, etc.

There are some types of errors (unknown server, CORS-related error when running in the wrong environment, a server timeout, etc.) that hit the error handling callback function, but do not seem to have enough data in them to give a meaningful message to the user, or it is highly browser-dependent - IE has details in the `message` and `description` fields, but I don't see anything analogous in Chrome/Firefox.

In these cases the error shows up in the browser console, but 99.9% of my users will never have the console open to see the specific message like:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myserver/v1/job/submit. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.`

In Chrome/Firefox I see lots of fields in the `httpResponse` object, like `config.data`, `config.headers`, etc. related to my request, but I can't find anything related to what I see in the console message anywhere.

I have had a suggestion to use an `interceptor`, but for `$resource` it appears that interceptors only handle responses and response errors, and I am already handling both of these cases - it doesn't appear to me that using an interceptor would have any extra information available to its handler.

Does the error just live "outside the scope" of the `httpResponse` or is there somewhere I can find it so that I can show it to the user?

```
$scope.submitJob = function(job) {

    $scope.submitting = true;

    jobService.submit({}, job,

        function (response) {
            $scope.submissionResponse = response;
            $scope.submitting = false;
            $scope.submitSuccess = true;
        },

        function (httpResponse) {
            // gets hit, but I don't see anything in it related to the CORS error
            // this will pop up a dialog showing the nature of the error, with whatever details can be determined from the httpResponse
            $rootScope.$broadcast('raise-error', { error: errorService.parse("Could not submit job", httpResponse) });
            $scope.submitting = false;
        }
    );

};
```

Comment: why you don't implement it using `httpInterceptor`, which would provide you control over response..& you can easily throw an error..

Comment: @pankajparkar I don't use interceptors (yet), but the little bit I had seen it looked like people were mostly using them to standardize error handling (which I might be able to take advantage of), but it looked to me like it was still really just calling the same function with the same `httpResponse`. Is that not correct?  Does an interceptor have access to data that my error handler does not?